# Do PHP functions need to return a value?

Tags: php, function, return

Is it necessary to return any value or does it improve the speed? Sometimes its needed to code functions that not necessary return a value, some just do a set of functions or echo something. Does returning a value improves 'something'?, something like return true or return false?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I just asked cause if something is returned, PHP stop reading the function. But, anyway, the function already reached its end, so the question came up. Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP functions do not need to return anything, and I doubt it would negatively affect the performance if you didn't return anything. If anything, it would positively affect the performance.

Comment: Can you show how returning "anything" would affect the performance positively?

Comment: @user3253002: I think I meant that if anything, *not* returning anything might improve the performance. But honestly I don't think you would be able to measure a difference either way -- it is such a small detail that it would almost certainly be overwhelmed by anything else in your script.

Answer (score 6):

but, if you omit the "return something;" command the implicit returned value will be NULL

Comment: Good info for adding the correct return type declarations

Answer (score 5):

No, returning a value from a function does not improve the speed of your script.

You do not need to return values from functions -> it is completely optional.